# Trim User Input in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable in an excel macro that I'm getting user input on.  It's the following:

```
UserInput = InputBox("Paste in your input, plz:")
```

The trouble with this is that, sometimes, many users will not check for erroneous spaces within their paste.  I'd like to essentially clean(trim(UserInput)) through macro/VBA code.  How can I do this?

Comment: `worksheetfunction.trim(UserInput = InputBox("Paste in your input, plz:")))`?

Comment: `Trim()` exists in `vba`, so no need for `worksheetfunction` @findwindow

Comment: `Trim()` will work if the erroneous spaces are before or after the entire string. If you want to clean up double spaces from within the string you could do something like `UserInput = Join(Split(UserInput, " "), " ")`

Comment: If you want to post an answer, I'll upvote..

Comment: @Cyril it exists,  but it behaves differently.   VBA trim strips leading and trailing  spaces.  WF does that plus it reduces all multiple space sequences in the string to single spaces

Comment: JNevill is the least ambiguous on this.  Just so it's concrete and unambiguous, the answer would be ```trim(UserInput = InputBox("Paste in your input, plz:"))``` or ```UserInput = trim(InputBox("Paste in your input, plz:"))```?  Clarity is important

Comment: @chrisneilsen but that is also how trim() works on the sheet as a function.

Comment: Why would trim work differently as a formula vs vba?

Comment: @chrisneilsen ...The more you know... i thought they performed like for like; thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SolarMike uhm...what's your point? I'm just pointing out the difference between vba.trim and wf.trim.  the Q is about vba, not formulas

Comment: @findwindow in vba if you call Trim without qualifying it, it defaults to vba.trim

Comment: @chrisneilsen ohhh that makes sense depending on which you want.

Comment: Just curious, but why are y'all associated with VBA, anyway?  There's more money in python.

Comment: I guess somebody's got to know VBA

Comment: I am not a programmer XD

Comment: I learned VBA to automate excel work as an accountant... I've since learned some python, but still find It much more convenient to use VBA at work. Especially since it comes with it's own compiling environment - my employer is more than skeptical about allowing any downloads of anything they don't understand.

Comment: Also, @Solar Mike and @chris neilson, Trim and WF.Trim are just different functions. there's no reason for them to work the same. Try this macro to test: `Sub TestTrim()
Debug.Print Trim(" Hello  World ")
Debug.Print Len(Trim(" Hello  World ")) - Len(" Hello  World ")
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Trim(" Hello  World ")
Debug.Print Len(WorksheetFunction.Trim(" Hello  World ")) - Len(" Hello  World ")
End Sub` In case it's not clear, each "debug.pr..." starts a new line

Comment: Instead of using `InputBox` I would make a custom form with whatever rules and logic you want for input sanitation. You can't quickly make a WinForm GUI in python, so you likely aren't familiar with how easy and powerful it is.